# flash object code change path automatically with domain instead of http://fpdownload.macromedia.com

Tags: javascript, flash, asp-classic

I am working on ASP classic and I want to run flash file in asp.
When I embed code in `<object>` tag with

```
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab
```

and `<embed>` tag set

```
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer
```

But when I view the page source it has changed automatically to the domain path like `https://www.example.com/abc/......`

**Note**: swf file is running correctly but cannot run smoothly. just play and stop buttons are displayed.

Comment: yes you right @wvxvw. I think the problem in .swf file. because when i run .swf file it cannot display any thing. Would you please tell me how can i check my .swf file version. because when i replace another .swf file with another file that is run successfully. How may i check my .swf file version?